# CSS3 Flip functionality (problems with backface-visibility)

Tags: css

I am following a CSS3 tutorial to offer cardflip functionality.

When the user hovers or touches the image, I wish for the image to flip over and display a 2nd image.

So far, I have:

```
    /* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
}
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .flipper {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
        -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Chrome and Safari */
    -moz-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Firefox */
    -ms-backface-visibility:hidden; /* Internet Explorer */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/* front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jP39d/

The problem is that the front image shows the image still despite me setting `backface-visibility: hidden;`, but reversed. Image 2 is nowhere to be seen!

[image: Reverse of 1st image]

Comment: Works for me or am I missing something in the question?

Comment: I just get the reverse of the 1st image on hover, not the back image. See updated question with screenshot

Comment: Chrome and in Coda's preview browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` besides `transform-style: preserve-3d;`. It should work now.

And I guess you want to use `-webkit-perspective` too because you only used `perspective`.

So, it's only a prefix issue. Propably you should add `-moz` and `-o` too if you want to support them.

Comment: Thanks... This works from my iPhone, when i touch the image. Any idea how I can get it back to original state when user touches it again? http://jsfiddle.net/b39fv/1/

Comment: @Gravy Lots of touch screen and mobile devices aren't hover-friendly. Try the using `:active` pseudoclass.